# How to use versioning in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

I want to create version(ing) for page and records inside my backend environment.
is their any difference between versioning and workspace?

Comment: you want to create version but you don't know what this is ?

Comment: Yes, i have create versioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workspace lets you version record related to a workspace and to publish this workspace in one go (or switch two workspaces).
Versioning is required for workspaces, but can be used without workspaces.

Usually versioning is only used together with workspaces to create staging environments with workflows in the backend.